# MariaDB - Make a column unique to another column

Tags: mariadb, unique-key

I have a little table for keeping track of tasks. If my table looks like this:

```
+----+---------+----------+-----------+
| id | project | task_num | task_name |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+
```

Can I make the task number unique to the project column? Such that I can have:

```
+----+---------+----------+-----------+
| id | project | task_num | task_name |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | Proj_1  | 1        | firsttask |
| 2  | Proj_1  | 2        | sectask   |
| 3  | Proj_2  | 1        | fdsfds    |
| 4  | Proj_2  | 2        | gg        |
| 5  | Proj_2  | 3        | gf        |
| 6  | Proj_3  | 1        | xx        |
| 7  | Proj_1  | 3        | xxx       |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+
```

If that makes sense?

Comment: Your Question is ambiguous enough to elicit Crafter's answer, which probably not what you wanted.  I see that the `task_nums` are starting over with each different `project` -- If that is really what you are after, say so.  Meanwhile, this question has been asked and answered several times on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (column1, column2, ... column_n);
```

As for you:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT proj_task UNIQUE (project, task_num);
```

Source: https://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/unique.php